# custom material or shader for 3d Label in godot engine

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I want to make a 3D label with a custom shader. I had done this easily before in the Unreal engine, But in godot engine I could not find that.

My question is simple:

How to make custom material or shader for 3d Label in godot engine?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `MeshInstance3D` with a `TextMesh`? Anyway, there is not easy way to do this with a `Label3D`, I'd say consider writing a [proposal](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues), or at least bring it to [discussion](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions). *I expect it easier to surface this in Godot than to hack it.*